# Does IronPython just use Python or to use IronPython do I need to know other programming languages other than python?

Tags: python, ironpython

I am planning on using IronPython to develop a GUI interface for some python code. Do I need to know any other programming languages other than python. Also if not are there any other GUI packages/addon's to python that only use python to implement and get the final product working?

Comment: You don't _need_ to know any other languages, but if you just want a GUI I'd use something like Tkinter, which just uses regular CPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know any other languages - modulo a few implementation differences, Python is Python is Python. You will, however, need to know the Microsoft windowing library, with which I believe you will have to interface to build a GUI.

Comment: To add to that, it would help to have a reading knowledge of C# or Visual Basic.NET, which most of the samples will be in.